# Variables between Node.js Server and Client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I run a simple http server with Node.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');
var sensor = require('ds18x20');
var temp = sensor.get('sensorID');

http.createServer(function(req,res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(index);
}).listen(80);

console.log(temp);
```

my index.html file:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
<body>
My temperature:
//space for variable: temp
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to print the server-side variable: temp in my index.html file. But I have no idea how to do it.

Maybe somebody can help me with the exchange of Variables from the server to the client.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As you can read in @WebServer's answer there is a variety of template engines in node.
I want to give you an example of using one of them - [EJS](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs):

First install it:

```
npm install ejs
```

server.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req,res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

  //since we are in a request handler function
  //we're using readFile instead of readFileSync
  fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      res.end('error occurred');
      return;
    }
    var temp = 'some temp';  //here you assign temp variable with needed value

    var renderedHtml = ejs.render(content, {temp: temp});  //get redered HTML code
    res.end(renderedHtml);
  });
}).listen(80);
```

Your view might look like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
<body>
My temperature: <%= temp %>
</body>
</html>
```

EJS also escapes `temp` (and other variables you pass to the view) for you, so you don't have to worry about XSS attacks.

**Edit**

You can also compile the template if you don't want to read the file on each request:

```
var http = require('http');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');

//we are not in a request handler so we may use readFileSync
var content = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf-8');
var compiled = ejs.compile(content);

http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    var temp = 'some temp';

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(compiled({temp: temp}));
}).listen(80);
```

**Edit 2 (answering your comment question)**

Here is a simple example of using Express and AJAX:

**server.js:**

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');  //tell Express we're using EJS
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');  //set path to *.ejs files
    app.use(app.router);
    //put your static files (js, css, images) into /public directory
    app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

//get some server data for sending it to the client
var getData = function() {
    return Math.random().toString();
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //render index.ejs file
    res.render('index', {val: getData()});
});

app.get('/ajax', function(req, res) {
    res.send(getData());
});

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
```

**views/index.ejs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/request.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Val: <span id="val"><%=val%></span></h1>

    <button id="loadRequest">Refresh</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**public/js/request.js:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#loadRequest').click(function() {
        $.get('/ajax', function(res) {
            $('#val').text(res);
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you a lot, this is exactly what i'm searching for! thanks thanks thanks

Comment: you're welcome :) By the way EJS is compatible with [Express framework](https://github.com/visionmedia/express)

Comment: Hey maybe you can help me a second time, i take a look at the ejs documentation and i do understand the basics. The next step is to refresh my variable temp, with a click on a button in my index.html. At this moment i solved this with a function at the server.js which i exports. But i only can read the new temp variable at the console, with console.log(temp). I can't refresh the html, i know its a little bit complicated. Maybe you have an example were i can take a look at. Thanks a lot

Comment: You should use AJAX. The scenario is following: user clicks a button, you send AJAX request (this is pretty easy with jQuery), node.js server takes the request, updates temp, and sends an updated temp as a response, then you update your HTML tag with a new value on the client. The easiest way to take a request (on a server side) - is to use Express. If you have any questions about an implementation - feel free to ask me

Comment: okay, first i have to take a look at Express, and how it works to takes the request and send a response. After this there will be more questions ;-)

Comment: Okay I don't know how it works. I build an html site with a link <a href="javascript:sendRequest()">Request</a>  this function build an new XMLHTTPRequest() and load a script for example info.txt which is in the same folder like my html file. This function is working, but i don't know how i can get a variable which is on the server side. Am I on th right way or is it totally wrong?

Comment: Assume you send GET request to `/get_var` with AJAX. With jQuery you can write `$.get('/get_var', function(res) {console.log(res);});` In Express you should write `app.get('/get_var', function(req, res) { res.send('some string'); });`. So you get `'some string'` as AJAX response. There might be any data from the server instead of `'some string'` (you will see this data in browser console). Client side gets this data and modifies HTML code. Not too complicated :)

Comment: okay, not too complicated? I don't think so :) I have a file: request.js: with the function `$("button#loadRequest").click(function() { $.get('/get_var', function(res) { console.log(res);}); });`but i don't have any idea for the implementation on my server.js file. The index.html has a button: `<button id="loadRequest" type="button">loadReq</button>`. Thanks for your help, maybe its a little bit too much which I don't know

Comment: hey, using EJS is there a way to retrieve the server data without using a DOM element???

Comment: if anyone sees this after the upgrade to Express 4
`app.configure` and `app.router` are now deprecated

Answer (score -1):

You need a templating engine to write some data into page.
check out https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-templating