# How to pass node variable to external javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, redis

I want to use node varible in html file which node.js is loading. 
Here is my code.

```
var cord  = [ '37.772323,-122.214897','21.291982,-157.821856','-18.142599,178.431',
'-27.46758,153.027892' ]

fs.readFile('./map.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
    throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(8000);
});
```

I want to use variable cord in  in map.html. any suggestion please.

Comment: You may find answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955697/variables-between-node-js-server-and-client)

Comment: i am sorry but how to pass this varible to external javascript ?

Comment: First you pass it to html file via EJS template engine (detailed explanation you may find in the above link). Then you may put it in `textarea` in JSON format. It may look like this: `<textarea id="cord"><%=JSON.stringify(cord)%></textarea>`. And last you retrieve on the client side javascript. With jQuery it is as easy as follows: `var cord = $.parseJSON($('#cord').val());`

Comment: And don't forget to hide this `textarea` with `display:none`

Comment: @Zub please consider writing an answer so that it can be accepted and the question marked as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass variables from node to html you should either write your own template engine, or use third party solution (like [EJS](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs)).

To install EJS, open terminal, go to desired directory, and type `npm install ejs`

Your server-side code may look like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');

var content = fs.readFileSync('./map.ejs', 'utf-8');
var compiled = ejs.compile(content);

var cord  = [ '37.772323,-122.214897','21.291982,-157.821856','-18.142599,178.431','-27.46758,153.027892' ]

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.write(compiled({cord: cord}));
    response.end();
}).listen(8000);
```

And here is the example of `map.ejs`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var cord = $.parseJSON($('#cord').val());
    alert(cord);
});
</script>
</html>
<body>

    <textarea id="cord" style="display:none;"><%=JSON.stringify(cord)%></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

And after opening `http://localhost:8000` in browser you will see an alert showing `cord` array.

More information about EJS you may find in the documentation:
https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs
http://embeddedjs.com/

Good luck!

**EDIT**

EJS is not the only template engine for node. Consider also [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/).
And here is a (bit outdated) [list of other template engines](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#templating). Choose the one you like :)