# Express 4 404 error handling cannot find module 'html' error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, http-status-code-404

I want to add 404 (and also 500) handling etc to my express app file. Im able to display simple text to the client when they get a 404 error, but now I want to display html instead of text. My 404.html is located in /app as you probably can see.

So far I have this in my app.js:

```
.....
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
app.get("/app", function(req, res) {
  res.redirect("index");
});
.....
.....
.....
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(400);
  res.render('404.html', {title: '404: File Not Found'} );
  //Also tried taking away the .html after 404 it still doesn't work.
});
```

And this is the error Im getting in console:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'html' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15) 
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25) at Module.require (module.js:364:17) at require 
(module.js:380:17) at new View 
(H:\Developer\Github\angularApp\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:43:49) at 
Function.app.render 
(H:\Developer\Github\angularApp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:503:12) at 
ServerResponse.res.render 
(H:\Developer\Github\angularApp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:818:7) at Layer.port 
[as handle] (H:\Developer\Github\angularApp\app.js:33:7) at trim_prefix 
(H:\Developer\Github\angularApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:255:15) at 
H:\Developer\Github\angularApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:216:9
```

Im not able to understand this error (obviously). Im also using Express 4.

Comment: As far as I know, `render` method goes hand-by-hand with a layout engine (EJS, Jade, etc.). [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21956217/2600208)

Comment: You may also send `404.html` as static via `res.sendfile('/path/to/404.html');`, but in this case you can't inject your variables (like `title`) to the page

Comment: I have tried adding `app.use('view engine', 'html');` but It didn't work. I will not be using EJS, Jade etc. btw. just html

Comment: Then `res.sendfile` would be helpful

Comment: the `res.sendfile('/path/to/404.html');` worked. Is there any problems using this method? And is it possible to use this for 500 errors aswell?

Comment: The only problem is that you can't pass variables to html as you did in your example (`{title: '404: File Not Found'}`)

Comment: ah yes, you write that in the other comment which I think I didn't actually notice until now. Thank you! :)

Comment: You're welcome. There is a common practice to serve just static files (without dynamic content), especially if you're using Angular :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use redirects if you just want to show the static html.  The path will be relative to /app in your case.

```
// Error handling - if all other routes fail
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.status(404);
    res.redirect('/404.html')
});
```

According to the express documentation (http://expressjs.com/faq.html) 500 errors are handled like normal middleware i.e.

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.send(500, 'Something broke!');
});
```