# Retrieving server data in the HTML head

Tags: authentication, backbone.js, web-frontend

I am wondering how can I get the data from a server response in the head of the html?

```
  <head>

    //how can I get JSON data sent from the server here?

   </head>
```

is this possible?

I am sending html with JSON data like so:

```
 res.render('userHome.html', {
        user: user
    });
```

...and I want to be able to "get at" the user JSON data in the front-end in a clean manner. I'd like to avoid using a DOM element to retrieve the server data.

Comment: What server side language are you using?

Comment: node.js and I am using EJS on the client

Comment: Here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955697/variables-between-node-js-server-and-client

Comment: I saw that, looks like they are retrieving data using EJS in the <body>...frankly this just seems really dirty to me

Comment: I'd like to avoid using a DOM element to retrieve the server data