# Using nodejs & expressjs: What's a good way of passing .env to html without templating?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, environment-variables

My html page makes an AJAX request to Node to get process.env. I do not have passwords or keys there. But, likely will need it in the future. Is there a secure way I can do this without templating?

client-side

```
// source.html    
$.get( "/env", function( data ) {console.log(data);});
```

Server side

```
// index.js
app.get('/source', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/source.html');
});

app.get('/env', function(req, res) {
      res.send(process.env);
});
```

I looked into EJS templating, but that seemed overkill for passing process.env as described in [Variables between Node.js Server and Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955697/variables-between-node-js-server-and-client).

Ideas:

1. App.get('/source', app.use(process.env.SOCKET_ADDR))? Am I overlooking an express route passing JS object option?
2. Not clean, but I could make routes for environment variables individually rather than calling the whole object. On the same thought, make a new env object that contains no sensitive variables.
3. Suck it up and template...

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish here....  If you want to get your env on the front-end via AJAX as JSON, I think you're already there. Are you trying to convert the env to HTML (like a `<ul>` or the like)?  If so, I think templating is your best bet (you can do that on server-side or client-side).  If your concern is filtering out sensitive information in the future, you would be best to whitelist the response....  More information on what your goals, and I can construct an answer.

Comment: I don't get how "secure way" and "templating" are related to each other. The one thing has *literally* nothing to do with the other. What's your concern? (If you want to make environment variable values queryable, create a route that accepts a parameter, whitelist the parameter values and set up a handler that returns the environment variable value after whitelisting.)

Comment: @EthanBrown goal is to have a socket.io application getting the required production environment variables. Not trying to convert env. Whitelist response sounds enticing. Goal is to filter out sensitive information.

Comment: @Tomalak My understanding is templating is a "secure way" you can load environment variables into html pages (not making env publicly accessible). My concern is security and best practices when not templating. You both mention whitelist parameter values so that sounds like the tree I should be barking up.

Comment: Templating is "secure" in that it helps prevent XSS attacks on your HTML source code. It will not prevent leaking sensitve server information, if that's what you mean. Those two things are entirely unconnected to each other.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have two concerns: security (possibly not relevant now, but will be in the future) and presentation (to template or not to template?).  It's still not clear to me what your presentation needs are, but I'll offer some suggestions about that.  We'll start with security.

Given that you may, in the future, have environment variables that expose details that are sensitive, I recommend *whitelisting* the environment variables that you return.  It will prevent (or at least reduce the likelihood) of sensitive information being exposed accidentally in the future.  Whitelisting means you are explicit about what you let through (blacklisting means you are explicit about what you do *not* let through).  Here's how I would implement a whitelist of environment variables to return (this just returns JSON; we'll talk about presentation later):

```
const envWhitelist = new Set([
    "TERM", "SSH_TTY", "PATH", "SHELL",
    "EDITOR", "LANG", "NODE_PATH",
]);
app.get('/env.json', function(req, res) {
    res.send(Object.keys(process.env)
        .filter(k => envWhitelist.has(k))
        .reduce((a, k) => (a[k] = process.env[k], a), {})
    );
});
```

NOTE: I'm using some ES6 features here.  Particularly arrow notation functions and the `Set` object.  This works in current versions of Node (v4.2.2 and up).

This allows you to specify what environment variables you consider "safe" to expose to the world.  I would be very careful here, you might be surprised what environment variables could lead an experienced hacker to a successful exploit.  For example, I wouldn't expose the PATH, or TERM, or frankly just about anything that I wasn't setting myself.  So be careful here.

I think blacklisting in this instance would be very dangerous (if you add an environment variable that contains sensitive information, you will have to remember *every time* to add it to the blacklist), but for completeness, here it is:

```
const envBlacklist = new Set([
    "SOME_SECRET_VAR", "DB_PASSWORD",
    "WHATEVER_ELSE",
]);
app.get('/env.json', function(req, res) {
    res.send(Object.keys(process.env)
        .filter(k => !envBlacklist.has(k))
        .reduce((a, k) => (a[k] = process.env[k], a), {})
    );
});
```

Okay, now let's talk about presentation.  So far, we've just been returning JSON (which is why I changed the endpoint to be `GET /env.json`), which lends itself to front-end presentation.  I.e., you could use an AJAX call and then dynamically construct HTML with jQuery or a templating library.  But if you wanted to get HTML from the server, it would be easy enough to do, even without a templating library.  Here's a whitelisted example using an HTML `<dl>`:

```
const envWhitelist = new Set([
    "TERM", "SSH_TTY", "PATH", "SHELL",
    "EDITOR", "LANG", "NODE_PATH",
]);
app.get('/env', function(req, res) {
    const keys = Object.keys(process.env)
        .filter(k => envWhitelist.has(k));
    res.send('<dl>' +
        keys.map(k => '<dt>' + k + '</dt><dd>' + process.env[k] + '</dd>')
            .join('') + '</dl>');
});
```

I'm not sure I think this example is better than using templates, but it is one way to avoid templating.