# How to display image from node.js server to jsp page?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, sockets, jsp

Is there someone can help me or give me a tutorial on how I can display the base64 string from Node.Js to JSP/HTML img tag?

Im passing base64 string to this Node.Js server from Java application.

```
var net = require('net');
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 6969;
var cl = require('./client.js');

net.createServer(function(sock) { 
console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);

sock.on('data', function(data) { 
  sock.write(data);
  var client = new cl.client(data);
}); 

sock.on('close', function(data) { 
    console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
}); 

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    console.log("Node NOT Exiting...");
});
}).listen(PORT, HOST); 

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the Base64 string start with `data:image/jpeg;base64`(the type may be different). 
If so, you can set the `src` attribute of img tag with it.

`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64XXXXXXXXX">`

Comment: Yes it is, but I dont know how to pass the string from the node server to my web app.

Answer (score 0):

If the base64 string that you are passing already has data:image/[image type];base64 prefix then you can just set it in the image source you don't need to do anything special.
Or just have a method to check it and add the prefix if you don't have it.

```
  function setBase64ToImage(baseString){
  // data:image/[image type];base64

  if(baseString.substring(0,4) != "data"){
    baseString = "data:image/png;base64," + baseString;
  }
  return baseString;    
}
```

and in your HTML img src tag

```
<img src=setBase64ToImage(data)>
```

If your question is how to pass data from node.js to the html file then you should use a template like ejs or something to make it easy.
https://github.com/tj/ejs or look at this question which anwers how to pass data from node to html.
[Variables between Node.js Server and Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955697/variables-between-node-js-server-and-client)